# How to find geographic coordinates of intersection point of two lines originating from two different geographic coordinates?

Tags: qgis, python, computational-geometry, calculate-geometry

I have two planes emanating from two different geographic coordinates as per wgs 84 reference ellipsoid namely (lat1, long1, alt1) and (lat2, long2, alt3) with a bearing b1 and b2 with respect to north. These two planes intersect to form a line. This line intersects wgs84 reference ellipsoid at a point latitude, longitude and altitude (lat3, long3, alt3) . 
How do I find this intersection point ?
Can some one explain the math behind this ?

Comment: You can't use altitudes for this calculation, or the lines could become something like coplanar curves. You need to define the problem in a better way. What kind of lines are they? What is the reference surface?

Comment: Thanks for asking clarification. Reference surface is WGS84. Lines are straight lines.

Comment: Please, include clarifications in the body of the question. Being WGS84 an ellipsoidal datum, I think that you are meaning that the reference surface is an ellipsoid of revolution. Straight lines can't be found over curved surfaces. Please, define the lines in a correct way. Still, I don't know to answer your question. But if someone knows how to answer you, I think they would need at least that the problem be well defined.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I understood what you mean.

Comment: There is nothing to apologize for. Excellent that you consider the problem as the intersection between planes. It seems to me that the simplest solution is on that path. I know that we must start from the Cartesian coordinates of the points, apply transformation matrices to find the equations of both planes, calculate the intersection between them, and then the intersections of the line with the reference surface. But I should start investigating on my own so I can answer, I hope someone with greater mathematical mastery can do it.